# Were the guests aliens?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, the-rocky-horror-picture-show

During *The Rocky Horror Picture Show* there is a group of guests who are obviously invited and 'in on it'. But, due to the rest of the movie, it seems nebulous whether these invited guests are meant to be human or alien.

Was this ever made clear, either in the film or in interviews?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [Rocky Horror Picture Show Wiki](http://rocky-horror-picture-show.wikia.com/wiki/The_Rocky_Horror_Picture_Show):

*Highlights mine*

> They are greeted at the door by the butler Riff-Raff and also meet the maid his sister Magenta who show them the **rest of their kind** (called the Transylvanians) and they all sing the show's must popular song ("Time Warp"). At the end they try to back away from the Transylvanians but they are stopped by the sudden appearance of Frank N Furter.

Riff-Raff and Magenta were definately aliens so 'The rest of their kind' infers that the guests were aliens as well.

[TVTropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Characters/TheRockyHorrorPictureShow) says:

> Party-goers from the planet Transexual who've come to Frank's Castle to see Rocky being unveiled.

[Stageagent](http://stageagent.com/characters/18160/the-rocky-horror-show/phantoms-transylvanians) says:

> The Phantoms / Transylvanians serve as the ensemble for the musical. They are fellow aliens from...

However, [this script](http://www.zen134237.zen.co.uk/Rocky_Horror_Picture_Show_Lets_Do_The_Timewarp_Again.pdf) states:

> INT. BALLROOM - NIGHT
>   The doors open REVEALING BRAD and JANET at the doorway of a
>   huge black-and- silver ballroom. At the furthest end is a
>   throne-like chair and, surrounding it, a theatre proscenium.
>   In the body of the room are TRANSYLVANIAN GUESTS. They are
>   the people BRAD and JANET passed on the road.
>   They are the Transylvanian Secret Agents - assembled on this
>   special occasion from all over the earth.

Which infers that they're from earth and therefore not aliens.

I'm not sure however that this is a proper script...

Comment: "Assembled on this special occasion from all over the earth" doesn't _necessarily_ mean they are originally from earth. (Just like aliens disguised as humans in the Men in Black movies.) But that line in the script _also_ doesn't mean they're aliens. It's unclear.

Comment: Though this is a good answer, I find it hard to accept because it still kind of goes two ways.